# How to specify model class dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, interface

Hi I'm new to interface and abstract class in C# and I'm stuck with a problem I'm creating a sample application and I need to save the details to db the save function is common for the app only the object is different for eg. `void Save(User data);` and `void Save(Admin data)` my question is how can I specify the User and Admin Class dynamicaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
public void Save<T>(T data) where T: class
{
    ...
}
```

This would allow you to call the `Save` method for any of the types e.g.

```
Admin admin = new Admin();
User user = new User();
dbClass.Save(admin); // T is implicitly inferred by the parameter type
dbClass.Save(user);
```

The constraint against the signature i.e. `where T: class` dictates that only classes can be passed as a parameter. However, given `string` is actually a special type of class in .NET you could technically call

```
dbClass.Save("string")
```

If you want complete control over the types you could have your classes derive from a base class or implement a particular interface and use that as the constraint e.g.

```
public class Entity
{
   ...
}

public class Admin : Entity
{
}

public class User : Entity
{
}
```

Then you would update your constraint to be `where T : Entity`, this would ensure you could only pass entities to the `Save` method.

Comment: This means you can call e.g. `Save(42)`. And I'm not sure that's what is wanted.

Comment: @svick the constraint dictates that only classes can be saved.

Comment: Also, I think you mean “inferred”, not “inherited”.

Comment: The constraint doesn't help much, you can still do e.g. `Save("some string")`.

Comment: @svick true, but that's really because a `string` is a "special" type of class. Regardless, I have taken your point on board, see update.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two options:

1. Make `User` and `Admin` implement the same interface (or inherit the same abstract class), something like `IDbEntity`. Your method would then be:

   ```
   public void Save(IDbEntity data)
   ```
2. Create a private generic method that saves the data and then two public wrappers, one for each type:

   ```
   private void Save<T>(T data)
   {
       // your implementation here
   }

   public void Save(User data)
   {
       Save<User>(data);
   }

   public void Save(Admin data)
   {
       Save<Admin>(data);
   }
   ```

Comment: The problem with the first approach is the type is lost so the context of the Save is lost i.e. am I saving a `User` or `Admin`? The second approach is better, but more work than what it needs to be.

Comment: @James If you need to know that, you can always use `GetType()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use generics for your save method

```
public void Save<T>(T data) where T: MyAbstractClass
{
    // your save method code here
}
```

You may use reflection to determine what class are you saving is you need something specific to one of your class `Admin` or `User`.

`Admin` and `User` must inherit from the same abstract class

Comment: If they inherit from the same class, why don't you specify that in the method signature?

Comment: you're right, i have edited my answer but i think the one from James is basically the same as mine but way more complete ;)